# How to handle promise rejection of chained functions and how to get the return?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have this simple chain of functions:

```
one(request, response)
  .then((data) => {
    two(request, response, data);
  })
  .then((twoData) => {
    console.log(twoData);
    three(request, response, twoData);
  })
  .then((threeData) => {
    four(request, response, threeData);
  })
  .then((fourData) => {
    next();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    return response.status(e.statusCode).send(e);
  });
```

My questions: 1- why the `console.log` statement always returns `undefined` even if function `two` does nothing but return a string? 
2- Why when any of these functions has an error `next()` is always called? Isn't it supposed to jump directly to the `catch` statement? This is given that function `one` returns valid data. Please help!

Comment: Inside your `.then(...)` handlers you are not returning a value.  The returned value from these is what would be propagated to the next `.then(...)` handler.

Comment: What @Alex mentions is why promises are so error-prone and hard. Use `async/await` instead.

Comment: @Alex oh that bloody return! Thank you!!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Thanks!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Actually promises are surprisingly simple when you realise that they are values and always need to be returned.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. But async/await doesn't require even that little knowledge (I know they are still promises under the hood, but it's not a necessary knowledge to benefit from async/await).